# Parsing XML With Single Quotes?

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing, html-entities

I am currently running into a problem where an element is coming back from my xml file with a single quote in it. This is causing xml_parse to break it up into multiple chunks, example: Get Wired, You're Hired!
Is then enterpreted as 'Get Wired, You' being one object, the single quote being a second, and 're Hired!' as a third.

What I want to do is:

```
while($data = fread($fp, 4096)){
        if(!xml_parse($xml_parser, htmlentities($data,ENT_QUOTES), feof($fp))) {
            break;
        }
    }
```

But that keeps breaking. I can run a str_replace in place of htmlentities and it runs without issue, but does not want to with htmlentities.

Any ideas?

**Update:**
As per JimmyJ's response below, I have attempted the following solution with no luck (FYI there is a response or two above the linked post that update the code that is linked directly):

```
function XMLEntities($string)
    {
        $string = preg_replace('/[^\x09\x0A\x0D\x20-\x7F]/e', '_privateXMLEntities("$0")', $string);
        return $string;
    }

    function _privateXMLEntities($num)
    {
    $chars = array(
        39  => '&#39;',
        128 => '&#8364;',
        130 => '&#8218;',
        131 => '&#402;',
        132 => '&#8222;',
        133 => '&#8230;',
        134 => '&#8224;',
        135 => '&#8225;',
        136 => '&#710;',
        137 => '&#8240;',
        138 => '&#352;',
        139 => '&#8249;',
        140 => '&#338;',
        142 => '&#381;',
        145 => '&#8216;',
        146 => '&#8217;',
        147 => '&#8220;',
        148 => '&#8221;',
        149 => '&#8226;',
        150 => '&#8211;',
        151 => '&#8212;',
        152 => '&#732;',
        153 => '&#8482;',
        154 => '&#353;',
        155 => '&#8250;',
        156 => '&#339;',
        158 => '&#382;',
        159 => '&#376;');
        $num = ord($num);
        return (($num > 127 && $num < 160) ? $chars[$num] : "&#".$num.";" );
    }
if(!xml_parse($xml_parser, XMLEntities($data), feof($fp))) {
            break;
        }
```

**Update:** As per tom's question below, magic quotes is/was indeed turned off.

**Solution:** What I have ended up doing to solve the problem is the following:

After collecting the data for each individual item/post/etc, I store that data to an array that I use later for output, then clear the local variables used during collection. I added in a step that checks if data is already present, and if it is, I concatenate it to the end, rather than overwriting it.

So, if I end up with three chunks (as above, let's stick with 'Get Wired, You're Hired!', I will then go from doing

```
$x = 'Get Wired, You'
$x = "'"
$x = 're Hired!'
```

To doing:

```
$x = 'Get Wired, You' . "'" . 're Hired!'
```

This isn't the optimal solution, but appears to be working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you use something like simplexml_load_file to parse your file easily ?

Answer (score 2):

I think having magic quotes enabled can mess up xml parsing sometimes - is this enabled?. You can disable this at runtime using

```
set_magic_quotes_runtime(0);
```

Edit: this may not be relevant if the source is not post or get, but I read in the PHP manual that it could cause odd behaviour anyway